# Error when building Kogito native images with Persistence profile enabled (quarkus-infinispan-client extension) witn ubi8 images

Tags: infinispan, quarkus, graalvm, kogito

While trying to build a simple [Kogito](https://github.com/kiegroup/kogito-examples/tree/master/jbpm-quarkus-example) application with the [Persistence](https://github.com/kiegroup/kogito-examples/blob/master/jbpm-quarkus-example/pom.xml#L107) profile enabled the build failed complaining that the lib stdc++ was not found:

```
 /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
```

The builder image is based on the ubi8-minimal and to build it the [s2i](https://github.com/openshift/source-to-image) tool was used with the following command was used:

```
 s2i build https://github.com/kiegroup/kogito-examples --context-dir jbpm-quarkus-example  quay.io/kiegroup/kogito-quarkus-ubi8-s2i:0.8.0-rc1 kogitotest:10.0 --runtime-image quay.io/kiegroup/kogito-quarkus-ubi8:0.8.0-rc1 --loglevel 5 --env MAVEN_MIRROR_URL=http://nexus.apps.spolti.cloud/nexus/content/groups/public/ --env NATIVE=true --env MAVEN_ARGS_APPEND="-Ppersistence"
```

As first hint I think it could be something related with the libstdc++-static because when running the same build on my local machine it works and the only difference I found around this the stdc++ lib was that my machine have the llibstdc++-devel and static packages while the image only have the libstdc++, tried the to install the devel one, but no luck thus I thought it could be something related with the static one.

**The fix:**

To solve this I had to symlink /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.25 to /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so
but not sure why on my machine it works without the symlink and have piratically the same libs available, eg libstdc++.so.6.0.27 with a symlink to libstdc++.so.6

Answer (score 0):

Proper fix:

Just install gcc-c++ package.